# Is there any particular reason why songs with Spanish lyrics are taking over?

Tags: history, music-video, music-business

I was reading the charts for most viewed youtube songs for the years 2017/2018 . In it, 7 out of the 10 most viewed youtube music videos are in spanish. [image]

Notice this wasnt like this before, in years prior to 2013 there were none and from there on it kept increasing slowly.

Also, I was taking a look at the list of most viewed youtube videos today. In it, of the top 100 songs, 38 are in spanish . I've been seen this chart getting more and more spanish speaking songs regularly. [Most viewed youtube videos in the past 24 hours](http://kworb.net/youtube/)

Is there any known reason why this is happening?

Comment: Top 100 most viewed youtube videos all time (it includes another chart with the top5 most viewed per year below, which is the screencaptured and posted here )  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos Top 100 most viewed youtube videos today http://kworb.net/youtube/ (Most viewed today 27/2/2018 40 in spanish, 39 in english, 21 in other languages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two reasons, 1) demographics and 2) culture.

First is sheer numbers. The number of Hispanic-Americans has risen from 10 million in 1970 to 50 million in 2010. In percentage terms, that's a rise from 5% of the U.S. population, to 17% over those 40 years.More to the point, it took that long for a generation of Spanish-speaking children to grow up and "take over" the music industry. A ratio of 38% Spanish songs to 17% (more like 19% today) is "only" 2 to 1.

The other question, of culture, is "why is the above ratio 2 to 1 and not 1 to 1 or less?" The reason is the greater push for cultural diversity. Over the past 50 years, American society has gone from "three flavors" (chocolate, vanilla, and strawberry) to Baskin-Robbins 31 flavors. More to the point, America is now exhibiting a preference for "spicy" (e.g. Hispanic) "flavors," over formerly bland Anglo-Saxon ones.

Comment: Great answer.  I would only add that pop music is one of the most "trendy" of all businesses, and the fact that there was one massive hit in Spanish recently (*Depacito*) inevitably means that other aspiring hits will follow.

Comment: I took a look at the top 100 Youtube videos today. 40 in spanish, 39 in english, 21 in other languages. And I mean worlwide, not for US Youtube only. BTW, last weekend I paid only 10 dollars for a party with one of the singers in the top100 in it, crazy, isnt it?